# Using scrapy to crawl post (output xml) and import to workpress ( wp\tool\import)

Tags: python, wordpress, scrapy

i crawl post and output xml file, but i can not import file by using wordpress import tools.
error: "Sorry, there has been an error.
This does not appear to be a WXR file, missing/invalid WXR version number"

[enter image description here][1]
How to fix its, thank you
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhEsd.png

```
        # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
 class TenSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ten'
    allowed_domains = ['tenhay.net']
    start_urls = ['https://tenhay.net/ten-hay-cho-con-gai']

    def parse(self, response):
        posts = response.xpath("//h2")

        for post in posts:
            title = response.xpath("//article[@class='post-6279 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail category-ten-hay-cho-con-gai entry boxed flex-entry col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 has-image-before_title column']")
            link = post.xpath(".//@href").get()
            yield  response.follow(url=link,callback=self.post_content,meta={'titles':title})
            
       
    def post_content(self,response): 
             
            yield {
                
               'title': response.xpath("//div[@class='section-content width-auto']/h1/text()").get(),
                'image url' : response.xpath("//figure/img/@src").getall(),
                'content': response.xpath("//div[@id='ftwp-postcontent']//text()").getall()
            }\
```